# Unable to get a blank form value from $_POST data adding name as value? (jquery validate ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation

I am using jquery validate and ajax to post a form but want to post a blank field with my data and am using:

```
<input type="text" name="blank" class="blank" />
```

When sending a form with this field by php post the value for $_POST['blank'] is "blank" and not "" as expected.

This is also the case when if I try

```
 <input type="text" name="blank" class="blank" value=""/>
```

If I use this:

```
<input type="text" name="blank" class="blank" value="this_value"/>
```

I get the "this_value" for $_POST['blank'] as expected.

Everything else works on the form perfectly except the blank field posting with a value matching its name instead of with a blank value.

Has anyone come across this and know a remedy?

Comment: Got around this by using $blank = $_POST['blank'] and checking the string value which returns as "".

Comment: Post form and jquery validation function.

Comment: i made a test and it's working perfectly to me [http://codepad.org/74Tc1vW7](http://codepad.org/74Tc1vW7)

Answer (score -1):

I have come across this before and the easiest solution for me was to try looking for whether a field exists in $_POST and, if not, assume it is blank:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('blank',$_POST)===FALSE)
{
    $blank='';
} else
{
    $blank=$_POST['blank'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I was wrong. Original answer is only correct in the context of checkbox-only forms.

Browsers do not send fields with empty 'value' attributes to the server. A better way to assign the server side variable is to use the ternary operator with an isset() condition:

```
<?php 
    $blank = isset($_POST['blank']) ? $POST['blank'] : '' ;
?>
```

More on php's ternary operator: https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary
See "Example #2 Assigning a default value"

Comment: `Browsers do not send fields with empty 'value' attributes to the server.` - who said you that?

Comment: +1 for @Col.Shrapnel - browsers _do_ send empty fields. Although I cannot remember if that's part of the specification or not.

Comment: @Carl: I recommend testing before posting an answer. It happens to us all when we're *sure* of something, that we might make a minor mistake.

Comment: @scraimer the only exception is a checkbox though. but the question was about text field, which is always sent

Comment: @scraimer and Your Common Sense, Thank you. I stand corrected. Browsers DO send fields with empty 'value' attributes to the server unless they are of type check box and the user has not checked them. To be fair, I did test this, but I happened to use a simple checkbox-only form because that was the file I had open at the time. Nevertheless, in the future I will attempt to be more comprehensive before posting. Thanks once more.

Comment: Carl - please update your answer... as it stands it is just wrong :-)